# Validate Start Time and End Time with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used boostrap timepicker for my start time and end time field and each for format is in AM/PM (10:00 PM) or (10:00 AM).
what I want to do is to validate to make sure that endtime field is always bigger than starttime field.

```
<input value="" type="text" class="form-control clinic-open time-picker" />
<input value="" type="text" class="form-control clinic-close time-picker" />

 $('.time-picker').timepicker({
                    minuteStep: 5,
                    defaultTime: false,
                    disableFocus: false,

 });
```

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 can u check?

Comment: Link to timepicker.js ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: its better if you include your html and js in the question as others has suggested. what you provide isn't enough.